# How to send different message to admin and user in php

Tags: php, forms, email, phpmailer

I want to send diifferent email to both admin and user.I dont know how to do that.
The code which i am sharing with you is sending same email to both admin and user.Please help me ..

Here is my code ;

```
$car = $_POST['category'];
$pick = $_POST['text1'];
$drop = $_POST['text2'];
$source = $_POST['text3'];
$email= $_POST['text4'];

$to="$email";
$subject="Web Enquiry";
$message="Hi,". "\r\n" . "\r\n" .
"You've received an email with following details, from the inquiry made at the website- mail@silvertaxi.com" ."\r\n"."\r\n".
"Car Category:"." "."$car"."\r\n".
"Source Location:"." "."$pick"."\r\n".
"Destination Location:"." "."$drop"."\r\n".
"Day and Time.:"." "."$source". "\r\n".
"Email:"." "."$email". "\r\n" ."\r\n". 
"Thanks & Regards,". "\r\n" .
"Web Admin"."\r\n" ;

$headers ="From:$email\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: admin@email.com' . "\r\n";
$headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso 8859-1";
if(mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers))
{
    echo "Your Message has been sent." ;
} else {
    echo "";
}
```

Comment: call `mail()` twice, each time with the different variables you want to send

Comment: How can you show me some demo?

Comment: mail(_VARS HERE_); mail(_DIFFIRENT_VARS HERE_);

Comment: This is a good example of why you should not call mail yourself. Use a library (like PHPMailer that you tagged this question with) which will avoid the format errors you’ve made. You’re using a user-submitted from address, which is forgery and will get your messages rejected by SPF checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call mail() function twice; one for user and another for admin. Remove the line

```
    $headers .= 'Cc: admin@email.com' . "\r\n";
```

from your code.
Then, define different messages for user and admin as you want.

```
    $to="$email";
    $subject="Web Enquiry";
    $message="....." //your message to user goes here

    $to_admin = "admin@email.com";
    $subject_admin = "...."; //subject for mail to admin
    $message_admin = "....." //your message to admin goes here
```

Use the mail() function twice to send different emails.

```
    if((mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers) && mail($to_admin, $subject_admin, $message_admin, $headers))
     {
      echo "Your Message has been sent." ;
     } else {
      echo "";
     }
```

Comment: User mail is going to spam ..Can you tell me why?

Comment: Add MIME version in your headers. $headers.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset= iso-8859-1\n";

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to check he is user or admin. If he is user you can add a condition statement for its another for admin. Like this:

```
if($user_role == "user"){
   //mail for user
   .....
}
if($user_role == "admin"){
   //mail for admin
   .....
}
```

If you have any question  feel free to ask.